# Mercurial pushing update to previous revision

Tags: mercurial

I ran `hg update -r REVISION` to revert a branch to a previous revision, but when I try to push this to a remote repository it says "no changes found". How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To revert the files to a previous revision you can use

```
hg revert -r REVISION
```

This will change your working directory files to what they were at that revison. Then you 
will need to commit these changes before pushing.

`hg update -r REVISION` changes the working directory's parent to be that revision as well as changes the contents of the working directory to that revision. This is not what you want here.

Comment: @Hypercube, note that if the sequence of canceled changes contains a merge (with a branch outside that sequence), it will be very tricky to carry out the same merge again. That is, reverting after a merge is not safe. You'd be better off creating a fresh branch that replays the changes (e.g., with `hg graft`), and deleting or abandoning the compromised branch.

Comment: Great, thanks!

Thank you @alexis, unfortunately I do have a merge. But the branch I want to revert changes on is the default branch; do you know how I could work around this?

Comment: @Hypercube I suggest giving more details about your situation if it is not straightforward - the merge etc. Perhaps another question?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up reverting it and it worked. I had done the merge with two heads, not two different named branches. Hopefully this won't lead to other problems later on.

Comment: If the two heads were on the main branch, and the merge was later than the commit you want to revert to, then there is no problem. Otherwise, depending on the situation, it can be trickier.

Answer (score 1):

`hg update` only affects the state of your working directory, not the repository itself.  If you want to "undo" the effects of one or more previous revisions, you will need to change the repository by committing a new changeset that reflects those changes.  You could do it manually but hg's builtin `backout` command makes this easy to do.  See a brief description [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/guide/#backing_out).  There is a detailed explanation of `backout` [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Backout).

Comment: `backout` will reverse the effect of individual revisions, so it will not return the repo to an earlier stage. `revert` is the right solution here.

Comment: `backout` is a more general solution but, yes, if you only need to remove a complete and contiguous line of children of a particular rev, `revert` is easier.

Comment: There is no reason why `backout` couldn't handle a range of changesets, but it currently doesn't. See this 2009 issue I filed - [hg backout should be able to backout a range of changesets](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1718).